# savefig() in jupyter (with matlab kernel) does not save figure properly

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, jupyter

I just installed matlab kernel and it works great so far—except savefig() command does not work.

For example:

```
figure
plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
savefig('myfig.fig')
```

This will save the figure but I cannot open myfig.fig in Matlab. I tried to open it but no response whatsoever.
Looks like the figure cannot be recognized by Matlab so it failed to open.

Any help?

Comment: what did you mean by `open`? Did you use openfig https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html ?

Comment: In jupyter notebook I can open the figure without problem using `openfig()`, however, when I try to open it in MATLAB program, nothing pops up.

Comment: May be a problem with your MATLAB installation, did you try reinstalling?